# Drawing stroked text with True Type Fonts

Tags: c++, algorithm, user-interface, graphics

Right now in my game I'm drawing true type fonts like this:

```
for(int i = linesSkipped; i <= maxitems + linesSkipped; ++i)
    {
        if(i >= (int)textRows.size())
        {
            break;
        }
        paintargs.graphics()->drawText(AguiPoint(textX - 2,
            textY - 2 + (i * getFont().getLineHeight())),
            textRows[i].c_str(),AguiColor(0,0,0),getFont());

        paintargs.graphics()->drawText(AguiPoint(textX + 2,
            textY + 2 + (i * getFont().getLineHeight())),
            textRows[i].c_str(),AguiColor(0,0,0),getFont());

        paintargs.graphics()->drawText(AguiPoint(textX,
            textY + (i * getFont().getLineHeight())),
            textRows[i].c_str(),AguiColor(255,128,0),getFont());

    }
```

So I draw it with an offset of 2, then with an offset of -1 .

It almost does what I want, but the top right and bottom left edges are still unstroked:

[image]

Is there a way to draw it such that it would look like stroking in Photoshop?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to draw the text in all corners! What you're doing is drawing in the top-left corner and in the bottom-right corner, which is respectively `X=-2, Y=-2` and `X=2, Y=2`.
What you need to do, is to draw them in the bottom-left and the top-right corner too, which would be respectively `X=-2, Y=2` and `X=2, Y=-2`.

Comment: Not applicable to greater radii, though.

Answer (score 0):

Which API are you using?  Is that GDI+?

You can draw the outlines at more locations before drawing the inside:

```
(x-2, y-2) (x, y-2) (x+2,y-2)
(x-2, y  )          (x+2,y  )
(x-2, y+2) (x, y+2) (x+2,y+2)
```

Or you can see if your graphics API has something like paths.  With paths, you tell the graphics library you want to start a path, then draw the text once, then end the path.  Once that's done, you tell the graphics library to "stroke and fill" the path.  This is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using FreeType

Comment: Suffers the same problems: low quality results and not applicable to greater radii. Isn't really different from Dlaor's solution.  In fact it's rip-off of his.

Comment: @artistoex:  To work well with all glyphs, you need to draw at all eight offsets.  Dlaor's four offets are not enough.  You can do greater radii, but it doesn't scale (performance-wise) very well.

Comment: As for my comment, you are right (I'm sorry for it being so harsh).  But I think text rendering has its cost as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you have no means to influence the text rendering method, draw the text in the first step and the stroke in a second step like so

```
r=5; //pixel-thickness of stroke 
for ( x = xmin; x<=xmax; x++ )
    for( y = ymin; y=<max; y++ )
       if ( isWhite(x,y) && orangePixelNearby(r,x,y) )
           putPixel(x,y)
```

Of course there are more efficient ways to do that but this one illustrates best how strokes are rendered.